# Дресскод, или дресс код, или дресс-код?

Tags: орфография

Как в русском языке договорились писать слово "дресс()код"? В словарях - варианты.
**Отвечаю на комментарии**. Меня смутила эта статья: [Википедия](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/907131). Не надо было мне писать "словари". Надо было указать конкретный адрес. Всех благодарю!!!

Comment: _Nika: В словарях - варианты._ === А в каких словарях?

Comment: @slava, ну такие слова в словник включает только Лопатин. Откуда варианты? )))

Comment: _behemothus:  @slava, ну такие слова в словник включает только Лопатин._ === Да нет, есть и в других словарях: http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=.  Но всюду -- дефисное написание:  _**дресс-код**_.   Никаких других _**вариантов**_ я не нашёл.  Хотелось бы узнать от _Nika_: _**Откуда варианты? )))**_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дресс-код** - это наиболее приемлемое написание слова, выбор которого можно объяснить.

1) **Дефисная форма** является промежуточной формой написания слов, тесно связанных между собой по смыслу, но при этом не утративших некоторую самостоятельность.
Несклоняемый иноязычный формант в этом случае стоит на пером месте и является **приложением,** что является обычной практикой написания подобных слов, например: гала-концерт, лейб-гвардия, прима-балерина.

2) **Слитное написание**  используется  том случае, когда образуется **слово с новым содержанием**, сравнить: обер-тон - старший офицер (приложение+сущ), но: обертон (в музыке) -  дополнительный тон, звучащий выше основного. В нашем случае (дресс-код) мы имеем именно приложение, стоящее перед существительным.

3) **Раздельное написание** "дресс код" (несклоняемое существительное  роли **несогласованного определения в препозиции**) нехарактерно для русского языка.

Answer (score 0):

Знакомая ситуация. )) Частенько встречаю разные варианты заимствованных слов в разных словарях, причем дело касается и написания, и произношения... Взял для себя за правило в подобных случаях ориентироваться на наиболее солидный (разумеется, с моей точки зрения) словарь. Либо смотришь, какой вариант чаще указывается в словарях...

Что касается вашего слова:

"дресс-код". Тут и особого разнобоя-то нет. ))

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: дресс-код.

См.: Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.